# Javascript Looping Logic

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'll explain it via wordings + screenshot

I have three containers which contains the following down below.

[image]

Each of them has different id's and same class.

```
<div id="container" class='list-cont'>
    <h2> One Two Three Four</h2>
</div>

<div id="container-1" class='list-cont'>
    <h2> Four Five Six </h2>
</div>

<div id="container-2" class='list-cont'>
    <h2> Seven Eight Nine Ten Eleven</h2>
</div>
```

The purpose of what I'm doing is, making each container's first half of words into different color, and the rest are different color too, like this one. But the **main problem** is, the code is constantly looping that I don't know why it's happening, the page reload non-stop.

[image]

**Code:**

```
//Count total number of div's which has a class of list-cont
var div_items = $(".list-cont").length;

for (var q = 1; q <= div_items; q++) {
  //If 1 the container who doesn't have "-" will get an update
  if (q = 1) {

    //Get value of h2 of the container who doesn't have "-"
    var s = $('div#container h2').html();

    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");

    //Number of words
    var str_length = s.split(' ').length;

    //Words in an array
    var str_array = s.split(' ');

    //Get total of first half of words
    var len_first = Math.round(str_length / 2);

    //Delete Value of h2
    $("div#container h2").html('');

    for (var ctr = 0; ctr < str_length; ctr++) {
      if (ctr >= len_first) {
        $("div#container h2").append(" <font color='#fdbd16'>"+ str_array[ctr] +"</font> ");
      } else {
        $("div#container h2").append(" " + str_array[ctr] + " ");
      }
    }
  } else {
    //Container has "-" like container-1 or container-2

    //Get value of h2 of the container who doesn't have "-"
    var s = $('div#container-'+ q +' h2').html();

    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");

    //Number of words
    var str_length = s.split(' ').length;

    //Words in an array
    var str_array = s.split(' ');

    //Get total of first half of words
    var len_first = Math.round(str_length / 2);

    //Delete Value of h2
    $("div#container-"+ q +" h2").html('');

    for (var ctr = 0; ctr < str_length; ctr++) {
      if (ctr >= len_first) {
        $("div#container-"+ q +" h2").append(" <font color='#fdbd16'>"+ str_array[ctr] +"</font> ");
      } else {
        $("div#container-"+ q +" h2").append(" " + str_array[ctr] + " ");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot wrong with your code, but the thing that's making it loop infinitely is this

```
for (var q = 1; q <= div_items; q++) {
    if (q = 1) {
        // q is now 1
        // so it stays lower than div_items (3) forever, the loop continues
    }
}
```

You want to check the value of q, not set it

```
if (q == 1) {
```